# This Omnisharp error don't let me start my first Godot project with C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

### I am getting this Omnisharp error again and again. I can't figure out what's the problem now.

```
    Starting OmniSharp server at 11/5/2022, 6:12:47 pm
    Target: d:\Study\Projects\Godot\C# Project.sln

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: c:\Users\anime\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.24.4-win32-x64\.omnisharp\1.38.3-beta.78\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 3536

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on Windows 6.1.7601.65536 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        Checking the 'DOTNET_ROOT' environment variable to find a .NET SDK
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        Using the 'dotnet' on the PATH.
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.32413.511 16.11.2 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.32413.511 16.11.2 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in 'd:\Study\Projects\Godot'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Did not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Detecting projects in 'd:\Study\Projects\Godot\C# Project.sln'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'd:\Study\Projects\Godot\C# Project.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in 'd:\Study\Projects\Godot'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Did not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location 'd:\Study\Projects\Godot' on host 5068.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: d:\Study\Projects\Godot\C# Project.csproj
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadAutoImportPropsLocator' specified could not be found.
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file 'd:\Study\Projects\Godot\C# Project.csproj'.
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadAutoImportPropsLocator' specified could not be found.  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.props
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject(String errorSubCategoryResourceName, IElementLocation elementLocation, String resourceName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, List`1& projects, SdkResult& sdkResult, Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImports(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, SdkResult& sdkResult)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate()
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate(IEvaluatorData`4 data, ProjectRootElement root, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Int32 maxNodeCount, PropertyDictionary`1 environmentProperties, ILoggingService loggingService, IItemFactory`2 itemFactory, IToolsetProvider toolsetProvider, ProjectRootElementCacheBase projectRootElementCache, BuildEventContext buildEventContext, ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, Int32 submissionId, EvaluationContext evaluationContext, Boolean interactive)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.Reevaluate(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary(EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.Initialize(IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectCollection projectCollection, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject(String fileName, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion)
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore(String filePath, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 projectConfigurationsInSolution, IList`1 loggers) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:line 160
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject(String filePath, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 configurationsInSolution) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:line 84
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load(String filePath, ProjectIdInfo projectIdInfo, ProjectLoader loader, Guid sessionId, DotNetInfo dotNetInfo) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectFile\ProjectFileInfo.cs:line 117
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<LoadProject>b__0() in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectManager.cs:line 305
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject(String projectFilePath, Func`1 loader) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectManager.cs:line 316
d:\Study\Projects\Godot\C# Project.csproj(0,0)
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadAutoImportPropsLocator' specified could not be found.  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.props
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject(String errorSubCategoryResourceName, IElementLocation elementLocation, String resourceName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, List`1& projects, SdkResult& sdkResult, Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImports(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, SdkResult& sdkResult)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate()
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate(IEvaluatorData`4 data, ProjectRootElement root, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Int32 maxNodeCount, PropertyDictionary`1 environmentProperties, ILoggingService loggingService, IItemFactory`2 itemFactory, IToolsetProvider toolsetProvider, ProjectRootElementCacheBase projectRootElementCache, BuildEventContext buildEventContext, ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, Int32 submissionId, EvaluationContext evaluationContext, Boolean interactive)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.Reevaluate(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary(EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.Initialize(IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectCollection projectCollection, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject(String fileName, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion)
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore(String filePath, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 projectConfigurationsInSolution, IList`1 loggers) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:line 160
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject(String filePath, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 configurationsInSolution) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:line 84
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load(String filePath, ProjectIdInfo projectIdInfo, ProjectLoader loader, Guid sessionId, DotNetInfo dotNetInfo) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectFile\ProjectFileInfo.cs:line 117
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<LoadProject>b__0() in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectManager.cs:line 305
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject(String projectFilePath, Func`1 loader) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectManager.cs:line 316

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: d:\Study\Projects\Godot\C# Project.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.InlayHints.InlayHintService
        Inlay hints requested for document not in workspace Location { FileName = d:\Study\Projects\Godot\PlayerController.cs, Range = Range { Start = Point { Line = 0, Column = 0 }, End = Point { Line = 21, Column = 0 } } }
[warn]: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.InlayHints.InlayHintService
        Inlay hints requested for document not in workspace Location { FileName = d:\Study\Projects\Godot\PlayerController.cs, Range = Range { Start = Point { Line = 0, Column = 0 }, End = Point { Line = 21, Column = 0 } } }
```

---

I already set "Omnisharp: Use Global Mono" to always
I also set "omnisharp.path": "latest"
I also have Visual studio 2019 version installed and as you can see it's picking up the msbuild of vs 2019 but i wanted to use vs code,
So i changed msbuild folder name and tried to run it again
Then i got this error

---

```
    Starting OmniSharp server at 11/5/2022, 6:38:25 pm
    Target: d:\Study\Projects\Godot\C# Project.sln

    OmniSharp server started.
    Path: c:\Users\anime\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.24.4-win32-x64\.omnisharp\1.38.3-beta.78\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 4236

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on Windows 6.1.7601.65536 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        Checking the 'DOTNET_ROOT' environment variable to find a .NET SDK
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        Using the 'dotnet' on the PATH.
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.dll
   at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(String fileName)
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildInstanceProvider.GetMSBuildVersion(String microsoftBuildPath) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\MSBuild\Discovery\MSBuildInstanceProvider.cs:line 67
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.Providers.MicrosoftBuildLocatorInstanceProvider.<>c.<GetInstances>b__1_0(VisualStudioInstance instance) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\MSBuild\Discovery\Providers\MicrosoftBuildLocatorInstanceProvider.cs:line 29
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray.CreateRange[T](IEnumerable`1 items)
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator.GetInstances() in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\MSBuild\Discovery\MSBuildLocator.cs:line 120
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.Extensions.GetBestInstance(IMSBuildLocator msbuildLocator, Version minimumMSBuildVersion, ILogger logger, Boolean& invalidVSFound, Boolean& vsWithoutSdkResolver) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\MSBuild\Discovery\Extensions.cs:line 84
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.Extensions.RegisterDefaultInstance(IMSBuildLocator msbuildLocator, ILogger logger, DotNetInfo dotNetInfo) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\MSBuild\Discovery\Extensions.cs:line 17
   at OmniSharp.CompositionHostBuilder.Build(String workingDirectory) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\CompositionHostBuilder.cs:line 71
   at OmniSharp.Stdio.Host..ctor(TextReader input, ISharedTextWriter writer, IOmniSharpEnvironment environment, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, CompositionHostBuilder compositionHostBuilder, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Stdio\Host.cs:line 49
   at OmniSharp.Stdio.Driver.Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Main>b__1() in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Stdio.Driver\Program.cs:line 74
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.<>c__DisplayClass146_0.<OnExecute>b__0(CancellationToken _)
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.<ExecuteAsync>d__157.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at OmniSharp.HostHelpers.Start(Func`1 action) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\HostHelpers.cs:line 30
```

---

Now i got no more solutions to do.
Please help with this thing

Answer (score 0):

the answer is actually in the problem Perform the instructions Omnisharpin tells you and you already have The Problem

```
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
            The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadAutoImportPropsLocator' specified could not be found. 
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
           Failed to load project file 'd:\Study\Projects\Godot\C# Project. csproj'."
```

it tells you here that **"Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadAutoImportPropsLocator"** is not available. Also, there is a problem with the **d:\Study\Projects\Godot\C# Project. csproj** file, if you can reproduce it, create this file.

**Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadAutoImportPropsLocator**: Uninstall this file with the .NET Uninstall Tool and **download the latest** .NET version

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar errors regarding the OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager

Installing the dev SDK 6 and the .NET Framework targeting pack for 4.7.2 fixed it.